# Disable DropDownList Within Gridview Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am really struggling with javascript programming and need help.

I am trying to disable 6 drop down lists client side that are within a gridview. Below is my current javascript that works except for the last line where I am trying to disable one of the drop down lists. I believe the problem is because the drop down lists are in gridview and java cannot find them. How do I find them?

```
<script>
                        function EnableAndColorButtons() {
                            document.getElementById('<%= Submit.ClientID %>').disabled = false;
                            document.getElementById('<%= Submit.ClientID %>').style.background = "Lime";
                            document.getElementById('<%= Submit.ClientID %>').style.borderColor = "Green";
                            document.getElementById('<%= Cancel.ClientID %>').disabled = false;
                            document.getElementById('<%= Cancel.ClientID %>').style.background = "lightcoral";
                            document.getElementById('<%= Cancel.ClientID %>').style.borderColor = "Red";                                   
                            document.getElementById('<%= InfoLbl.ClientID %>').innerHTML = '(Continue to make changes or click submit if finished)';                                
                            document.getElementById('<%= MakeChangeslbl.ClientID %>').innerHTML = 'You must click "Submit Changes" or "Cancel Changes" above before making Assignment changes below!';
                            //The above is working, but the below is not probaly because the drop down lists are within gridview1
                            document.getElementById('<%= DropDownList1.ClientID %>').disabled = true;
                        }
                    </script>
```

My Gridview where the drop down lists are located looks like this:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" DataTextField="FullDetails" DataValueField="FullDetails" Font-Size="Medium" Height="50px" OnDataBinding="DropDownlist1_DataBinding1" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="230px">
                                            </asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: try change autopostback to false and check if it is working, i believe the javascript that you write is working, just the post back is causing the issue here

Comment: I need autopostback for the functionality of the drop down list to work properly. I did try to change autopostback to false for testing and the drop down list is not getting disabled.

Comment: Dang... thought this was going to be an easy one for someone...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out a solution!!!

What I did was right click on my drop box with chrome browser and clicked inspect element. There I found the the id of the dropbox equaled "GridView1_DropDownList1_0".

I then did the following in my Javascript and it worked!!

```
var ddl1 = document.getElementById("GridView1_DropDownList1_0");
ddl1.disabled = true
```